# Android FEST not compiling properly for unit tests in IDE

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-studio, fest

For some reason, Android Studio is not properly compiling the Android `FEST` library (?).

This line,

`assertThat(someView).isNotVisible();`

causes this exception to be thrown:

`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/fest/assertions/api/ANDROID : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

and the import that i used is: `import static org.fest.assertions.api.ANDROID.assertThat;`

What's going on?

Oh, and it should be noted that the gradle task to run unit tests run just fine (but just not for IDE).

Comment: i.e. `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home ` ->  `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis means that the library was compiled with a later version of Java than what you're using to do builds in the IDE. v51.0 is Java 7, so you need to have JDK 7 available and set Android Studio to use it via Project Structure > SDK location.

Note that you don't need to run the IDE itself using Java 7 if you don't want, and you don't have to turn on Java 7 compatibility in your projects; you just need to use Java 7 to do the builds themselves.

Comment: you, sir, are a life saver. i had a hunch that was the case, but i initially thought that changing the JDK was done through Preferences, but it's actually Project Structure. thanks!